# Erlang - Can a module name start with a capital letter?

Tags: erlang

Erlang Can a module name start with a capital letter?

Comment: What happened when you tried it ;)

Answer (score 17):

A module name is an [atom](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id64272), so it must normally start with a lowercase letter, unless you enclose it in single quotes. This is actually possible:

```
%% in Foo.erl
-module('Foo').
...

%% in Erlang shell
1> 'Foo':foo().
"foo"
```

But completely horrible, so don't do this.

Comment: I 2nd it is a bad idea. Ther idiomatic erlang style is that module names are all lowercase, underscore_separated.

Comment: Also, case sensitivity/coercion of filenames on different platforms could throw a monkeywrench in there.